# Docker support for socket operations on Jenkins

Tags: networking, docker

I have to support a Continuous Integration (Jenkins) machine where I need to run my tests inside a docker.

The test includes creating a tap interface and then using it to communicate to the outside world (internet) using sockets. I was able to successfully create a tap interface inside the docker using the options
"--cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device=/dev/net/tun" when I start my docker image on Jenkins. However I am not able to create a socket communication. It fails in socket connect(). The error I receive when I call socket connect() is

"Socket error received: Connection refused. Bailing out."

I basically want to connect to a example.com and read a webpage from inside a docker. What is missing in the docker image to get socket operations working ?

Below info on how docker is started:

```
stage('test') {
            agent {
                 docker {
                     image 'my_test_image'
                     args '-v /home/jenkins/.ssh/:/home/jenkins/.ssh:ro -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device=/dev/net/tun'
                 }
            }
```

Regards, ky

Comment: You say you create a TAP interface, but what is it connected to?

Comment: tap is bridged with the ethernet eth0.

Comment: And what’s the other end connected to? Because I don’t see why you would need a TAP interface to connect to some resource on the network, except if your application is somehow making use of TAP interfaces.

Comment: App uses tap interface and there was a need to use tap because we wanted one interface for incoming traffic and another for outgoing. So actually we have 2 tap interfaces.

Comment: more over we use our own IP stack (and not linux), so either use the raw ethernet packets or use TAP interface. Tap was a better choice as applications could easily use it

Comment: I see. I have no real experience with this special case. Sorry. I can only offer one more hint: Verify that Linux networking works in the container, preferably with your bridge in place.